# How to implement a connection Master/slave PostgresSQL using Databases FastAPI

Tags: python, database, postgresql, fastapi

Good day The official documentation uses the line to connect `"postgresql://user:password@postgresserver,postgresserver,postgresserver/db"`.
How to implement a connection Master/slave? if you change the line, parsing errors will come out. I could not find any other options

Comment: Ideally connection string doesn’t have to imply master and slave. For e.g if its a patroni HA setup, the “driver” is where you specify “always connect to master” amd specify both the pg servers in the connection string.

Comment: In most cases this is handled by e.g. `pgPool` in front of the servers